# Python: Can't import a function from another.py file

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio, importerror, scapy, nameerror

I have a file named handshake.py. Where there is a function send_data(argument). I want to import that function into another file named siptest.py. I am encountering two problems. I am using microsoft visual studio with windows 7, 64-bit.
1) I can't import function. I have tried using,

```
from handshake import*
handshkae.send_data(argument)
```

Which give me an error.

```
NameError: global name 'handshake' is not defined
```

Another option I have tried is using

```
import handshake
handshake.send_data(argument)
```

Which gives me an attribute error.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'send_data'
```

If I use it the other way, such as

```
from handshake import send_data
```

2) MS Visual studio says. No test discovered, please check the configuration settings but I still can run the test somehow. and it says that the test is failed because of Import Error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name send_data
```

Both of the said files are in same directory. Plus the function is defined in a class 'TCPhandshake' in handshake.py

Comment: Is handshkae.send_data(argument) a typo?

Answer (score 15):

One possible reason: there exists reference cycle between module a.py and b.py:

In `a.py`: `import b`
In `b.py`: `import a`

The solution is to break the cycle. You need to make it clear which module should do what and reduce the dependence.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure both files are in the same directory and try:

```
from handshake import send_data
```

If this does not work, try to rename handshake.py file.

Comment: I have edited some information in last line. please look at that. May be it will give more clarity to my question and yes both files are in the same directory. I have tried by changing name. Both problems still persist as mentioned in my question. i.e. ImportError and MS Visual studio stops recognizing the tests

Comment: Did not notice your function was defined inside a class. Try import the class first, then instanciate the class:    from file import TheClass
theclass = TheClass()

Comment: Thanks, @voyager_1, for your suggestion. I have had a similar problem when importing functions from a Py file. Changing the Py file name helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are both `handshake.py` and `siptest.py` in the same directory?

If not You can try this:
    1) Add `__init__.py` empty file to the directory that contains `handshake.py`.
    2) Then add the path to that directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1):

make sure the function is in the path

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/directory/tothe/handshakefile/')
```

and then

```
import handshake
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple, but for me it worked to restart the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error using visual studio code. I literally just had to save the contents of the first and I was able to import the

Comment: import the what?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, That happened while I tried to run the program from another directory by using python /home/name/workspace/test.py

Fix I tired.

```
import sys
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
```

This need to be added at the beginning.
This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to import files in the same directory by implementing keyword as and a object variable for example

```
import file as fileObj
```

But the downside is that when you want access to the imported files variable you have to first take `fileObj.fileObjVariable.`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding/updating the environment variable **PYTHONPATH** which should point to the folder that has **handshake.py**

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure the files all are located in the root of the project, then this will work:

```
import handshake
handshake.send_data(argument)
```